What number completes the sequence? 2, 1, 7.5, ...,
What number completes the sequence?
2  , 1 , 7.5 , 6.5 , 5 , 6.5 , 7.5 , 5 , 6.5 , 7.5 , 1 , 6.5 , 7.5 , 6.5 , 5 , 4.5 , ...

Hi, Welcome to puzzling.se! Is this a sequence puzzle you created or a puzzle you found elsewhere which you need help to solve?

@ACB It is a puzzle I created.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Looks like something related to music.

I think the comment made by WhatsUp is correct that

 This is related to music

Specifically,

 Convert each number to the corresponding letter of the alphabet (1-> A, 2->B, ...) with the caveat that the additional 0.5 sharpens the corresponding note. This gives the pattern
 B A G# F# E F# G# E F# G# A F# G# F# E D#

Now, it's a little tricky to identify without the rhythm but I think the tune here is

 The refrain from the Christmas Carol Deck the Halls
 and so the final note is E which corresponds to the number 5.

Note:

 This is also what we would expect as the four sharps are suggestive of the scale of E major and we would generally expect the melody to be resolved by the root note.

